# Using LINQ to select a byte array

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having some trouble selecting a byte[] from inside of a list of objects model is setup as:

```
public class container{
    public byte[] image{ get;set; }
    //some other irrelevant properties    
}
```

in my controller I have:

```
public List<List<container>> containers; //gets filled out in the code
```

i'm trying to pull `image` down one level so I am left with a `List<List<byte[]>>` using LINQ
so far I have:

```
var imageList = containers.Select(x => x.SelectMany(y => y.image));
```

but it is throwing:

```
cannot convert from 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<byte>>' to 
'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<byte[]>>'
```

Apparently it is selecting the byte array as a byte?

Some guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Firstly, it would be a really good idea to follow .NET naming conventions, e.g. `Container` and `Image`.

Comment: @Jon- sorry these are dummy names not copy/pasted from my code

Comment: If you're using better names in your code, then please use better names in your examples, too. Anything unconventional detracts from the readability of the code - and even though this code isn't going into production, you're still asking people to read it.

Comment: Ah yes I completely didn't consider that. I'll keep that in mind in the future! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't want `SelectMany` for the `image` property - that's going to give a sequence of bytes. For each list of containers, you want to transform that to a list of byte arrays, i.e.

```
innerList => innerList.Select(c => c.image).ToList()
```

... and then you want to apply that projection to your *outer* list:

```
var imageList = containers.Select(innerList => innerList.Select(c => c.image)
                                                        .ToList())
                          .ToList();
```

Note the calls to `ToList` in each case to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `List<T>`.